# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Iface

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, spark-thriftserver

I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Iface` exception in runtime when I call this API in the browser, `http://localhost:8082/hive/default/tables`.

```
/home/ravi/dev/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/logs/spark-stellapps-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-OE-LPT-L-1221.out
Spark Command: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -cp /home/stellapps/arthadev/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/conf/:/home/stellapps/arthadev/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --host OE-LPT-L-1221 --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
```

I stared Spark and Thriftserver.

```
Spark: http://localhost:8080/
ThiftServer: http://localhost:4040/environment/
```

What can I try next?